Why does this always write to memory address 0xb8000?
In the function "write" I take a char c. If c is a letter, number or symbol I print it and increment x. But, the char is always stored in memory address 0xb8000 rather than 0xb8000 + line + (x++).
static void write(const unsigned char c) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        ++y;
        x = 0;
    } else if (c == '\r')
        x = 0;
    else if (c < ' ');
    else {
        int offset = y * screen_width + (x * 2);
        VGA_BASE[offset] = c;
        VGA_BASE[offset + 1] = style;
        ++x;
    }

    if (x >= screen_width) {
        ++y;
        x = 0;
    }

    if (y >= screen_height)
        scroll(y - screen_height + 1);

    set_cursor();
}

Here is the full file,
terminal.c
#include "include/terminal.h"

#define VGA_BASE ((volatile unsigned char *)0xB8000)

static const int screen_height = 25, screen_width = 80;
static int x = 0, y = 0;
static char style = 0x0F;

static void set_cursor() {

} 

static void scroll(const int count) {

}

static void write(const unsigned char c) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        ++y;
        x = 0;
    } else if (c == '\r')
        x = 0;
    else if (c < ' ');
    else {
        int offset = y * screen_width + (x * 2);
        VGA_BASE[offset] = c;
        VGA_BASE[offset + 1] = style;
        ++x;
    }

    if (x >= screen_width) {
        ++y;
        x = 0;
    }

    if (y >= screen_height)
        scroll(y - screen_height + 1);

    set_cursor();
}

void putc(const unsigned char c) {
    write(c);
}

void puts(const char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        write(*str);
        ++str;
    }
}


and the remaining files
boot.s
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

KERNEL_LOCATION equ 0x1000
CODE_OFFSET equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_OFFSET equ gdt_data - gdt_start

mov [boot_drive], dl

mov ax, 0x00
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

mov bx, KERNEL_LOCATION
mov dh, 0x20
call load_kernel
; call graphics_mode
call text_mode

load_gdt:
    cli
    lgdt[gdt_descriptor]
    
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x01
    mov cr0, eax
    
    jmp CODE_OFFSET:start_pm
    jmp $

load_kernel:
    push dx

    mov ah, 0x02

    mov al, dh
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, [boot_drive]

    int 0x13
    jc .disk_error

    pop dx
    cmp dh, al
    jne .disk_error

    cmp ah, 0x00
    jne .disk_error
    ret

.disk_error:
    mov si, kernel_load_error
    call print_string
    jmp $

graphics_mode:
    mov ax, 0x13
    int 0x10
    ret

text_mode:
    mov ax, 0x03
    int 0x10
    ret

print_string:
    lodsb
    test al, al
    jz .done

    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov bl, 0x03
    int 0x10
    
    jmp print_string

.done:
    ret

boot_drive:
    db 0x00

gdt_start:
    null_seg:
        dd 0x00000000
        dd 0x00000000

    gdt_code:
        dw 0xFFFF       ; Limit
        dw 0x0000       ; Base
        db 0x00         ; Base
        db 0b10011010   ; Access Byte
        db 0b11001111   ; Flags
        db 0x00         ; Base

    gdt_data:
        dw 0xFFFF       ; Limit
        dw 0x0000       ; Base
        db 0x00         ; Base
        db 0b10010010   ; Access Byte
        db 0b11001111   ; Flags
        db 0x00         ; Base
gdt_end:
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

[BITS 32]
start_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_OFFSET
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    jmp KERNEL_LOCATION

kernel_load_error:
    db 'Error while loading sector!', 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00

times 510-($-$$) db 0x00

dw 0xAA55

kernel_entry.s
[BITS 32]
[extern start]

section .text

kernel:
    call start
    jmp $

kernel.c
#include "include/terminal.h"

extern char *end;

void start(void) {
    putc('G');

    return;
}

and the Makefile that builds the program
Makefile

AS=nasm
ABFLAGS=-f bin
AOFLAGS=-f elf

CC=i386-elf-gcc
CFLAGS=-ffreestanding -m32 -g -c

LD=i386-elf-ld
LFLAGS=-Tkernel.ld --oformat binary

SRC=src
BOOT=$(SRC)/bootloader
KERNEL=$(SRC)/kernel
OBJ=obj
BIN=bin
BUILD=build

SRCS=$(wildcard $(KERNEL)/*.c) $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
OBJSK=$(patsubst $(KERNEL)/%.c, $(OBJ)/kernel/%.o, $(SRCS))
OUTPUT=$(BUILD)/OS.img

all: clean $(OUTPUT)

run: clean all
    qemu-system-x86_64 -hda $(OUTPUT)

debug: clean all
    qemu-system-x86_64 -hda $(OUTPUT) -monitor stdio


$(OUTPUT): $(BUILD) $(BIN) $(OBJ) $(OBJS) $(OBJSK)
    $(AS) $(ABFLAGS) $(BOOT)/boot.s -o $(BIN)/boot.bin
    $(AS) $(AOFLAGS) $(KERNEL)/kernel_entry.s -o $(OBJ)/kernel/kernel_entry.o
    $(AS) $(AOFLAGS) $(KERNEL)/x86.s -o $(OBJ)/kernel/x86.o
    $(LD) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJSK) $(OBJ)/kernel/kernel_entry.o $(OBJ)/kernel/x86.o -o $(BIN)/kernel.bin
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(OUTPUT) bs=512 count=2880
    dd if=$(BIN)/boot.bin of=$(OUTPUT) bs=512 conv=notrunc
    dd if=$(BIN)/kernel.bin of=$(OUTPUT) bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc


$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c $(SRC)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/kernel/%.o: $(KERNEL)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/kernel/%.o: $(KERNEL)/%.c $(KERNEL)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


$(OBJ):
    mkdir -p $(OBJ)
    mkdir -p $(OBJ)/kernel

$(BIN):
    mkdir -p $(BIN)

$(BUILD):
    mkdir -p $(BUILD)


empty: clean
clear: clean
clean:
    clear
    rm -rf $(OBJ)
    rm -rf $(BIN)
    rm -rf $(BUILD)

and the linker file
kernel.ld

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x80000000;

    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }

    . = 0x1000;

    .text : { *(.text) }
    
    end = .;
    _end = .;
    __end = .;
}

I've, tried changing the starting values of x and y to see if it would store in a different address, but it still stored in 0xb8000.

OT: Please remember that for any pointer or array p and index i, the expression *(p + i) is exactly equal to p[i]. The latter is usually easier to understand at a quick glance (and less to write). It would require extra parentheses in your macro, which would be a good idea anyway.

I see that you need a pointer to color screen video memory address 0xb8000.  I always did it like this: #define VidMem ((unsigned char far *)0xB8000000L)  . . . I know the extra parenthesis may seem trivial.  Also, you may need to omit the far keyword -- and you might also re-try it with the smaller address value as you had it:  0xB8000.  In either case, the added parenthesis may make a difference.

What compiler you using -- Borland Turbo C by any chance?  I'm assuming you're in a 16bit environment/OS too, yes?

By the way, that "full file" doesn't have a main function (or similar), so you're not showing us a [mre]. We don't know what's really happening.

What compiler do you use? What compilation flags? Values above 0xB8000 seem to be never read back by the program. Compiler doesn't know that it's a video memory, so can optimize out any writes there. Try #define VGA_BASE ((volatile short *)0xB8000), assuming short is 16-bit. Or ((volatile uint16_t *)0xB8000)

As we do not see what you try to print, we cannot judge what might go wrong. Is your scroll function really empty or did you just not copy it into the question? You should run your program in a debugger and step through your code. Then watch the content of your variables.

I have made a simplification of your example here: https://godbolt.org/z/srx7EYv1e.
I think it does things ok-ish. Maybe try for beginners to declare VGA_BASE volatile: volatile short *VGA_BASE = (short *)0xB8000;. This will force the compile to omit optimizations on the assignment.

Also very important information: How are you building? What is your host and target system? Are you creating your own operating-system kernel, or are you building for an old DOS-type system? Or do you just build for any modern operating-system (like Windows, macOS or Linux)? Please [edit] your question to give us all details that has been requested. Otherwise your question will be closed.

@tl-photography.at Do you have an explanation how missing volatile might result in writing everything to the first location as claimed by the OP?

And please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist.

Minor: #define VGA_BASE (short *)0xB8000 better as #define VGA_BASE ((short *)0xB8000).
